# how to bind two classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

hello community I have a problem I have two classes product and price are related, so I am creating a form in which I need to put in the bind-value a property that comes from both classes, but when I run the application it does not show me the form.

the problem is in this line:

```
<InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Producto.Precio.PrecioSinImpuesto"></InputNumber>
```

i need property `PrecioSinImpuesto` but it is in the price class and not in the product class

How can I make that bind work?

this is my two class:

```
  public class Producto
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ProductoId { get; set; }
        public Guid InquilinoId { get; set; }        
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public decimal Precio_Publico { get; set; }
        public string Detalle_producto { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha_publicacion { get; set; }
        public bool Activo { get; set; }     
        public string Img_Producto { get; set; }     
        public string ClaveProducto { get; set; }
        public string CodigoBarras { get; set; }
        public Concepto VigenciaPrecio { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Precio> Precios { get; set; }

         
        public Guid ImpuestoId { get; set; }
        public Guid PrecioId { get; set; }

       
        public List<CategoriaProducto> CategoriaProducto { get; set; } = new List<CategoriaProducto>();
        public List<ProductoPersona> ProductoPersona { get; set; }  
        public virtual Impuesto Impuesto { get; set; }
        public virtual Precio Precio { get; set; }

        
        public string NombreCortado {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Nombre))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                if (Nombre.Length > 60)
                {
                    return Nombre.Substring(0, 60) + "...";
                }
                else
                {
                    return Nombre;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Precio
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid PrecioId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fecha_Inicio {get; set;}
        public DateTime? Fecha_Default { get; set; }//ver si la podemos eliminar
        public DateTime? Fecha_Final { get; set; }      
        public decimal PrecioSinImpuesto { get; set; }
        public Concepto ListadoPrecios { get; set; }//mayoreo menudeo
    }
```

console error when entering the product form:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at BlazorApp.Client.Pages.Producto.FormularioProducto.<BuildRenderTree>b__0_1 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder2) [0x002de] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent (System.Int32 sequence, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment fragment) <0x316ab58 + 0x0001e> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CascadingValue`1[TValue].Render (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder builder) <0x368aa18 + 0x00012> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment renderFragment) <0x30c0dd8 + 0x00062> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry) <0x30c0798 + 0x0004c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue () <0x30bfcd0 + 0x00098> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When

```
<InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Producto.Precio.PrecioSinImpuesto"></InputNumber>
```

gives you a null-reference exception then either `.Precio` or `.Precio.PrecioSinImpuesto` is `null`.

This is caused by how you load the data, not by Blazor. You probably need to `.Include()` things in your query. But you didn't post that part, no precise answer is possible.